# Powershell random passwords and for-loop

Tags: powershell

```
$users = @("a", "b", "c")

ForEach ($user in $users){
      $Passwords = ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,3))
      Write-Host "Password = " $Passwords
      Set-LocalUser -Name $user -Password ($Passwords | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

}
```

I am trying to see if I can assign randomly-generated passwords to a pool of users that I have.

My thought process was like.. the for-loop would produce a password for each number of users and then assign each password to the users one by one.

I tried using a nested for-loop, but no luck.

Any brilliant fix or suggestion?!

Thank you:)

Comment: does it work when you run just one account manually?

Comment: No; I actually tried with just one user, and back-tested it with the generated password. Still throws a authentication failure...

Comment: “No luck” tells us nothing. Errors? Doesn’t change?

Comment: my bad. No error. The code runs and outputs a generated password, but when I try to log in with the password, it does not let me due to the authentication failure.

Comment: @doghoney - please, add all that info - and any other pertinent info - to your Question. scattering details in the comments is ... counterproductive. [*grin*]

Comment: It works fine. Are you running as admin?